# Sitecore 7.1 "Select media" button disabled

Tags: user-interface, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.1

I have the following issue after upgrading Sitecore for one of our projects from version 6.5 to version 7.1: after the upgrade the "Select media" and "Insert link" buttons in the dialog boxes with the same names (in content editor) are not working. The "Select media" button is permanently disabled and the "Insert link" button does not respond, even though it is active. Also, in both dialog boxes, the Cancel button is enabled but non-functional (it doesn't close the dialog box when clicked). Could you please provide any hints or tips for debugging this issue? Did anyone else experience this behavior on Sitecore 7.1 ?

Comment: Check the logs to see if there are any relevant errors and warnings.

Comment: As well as the logs, any errors in the javaScript console of your browser? Press F12 to open the dev console.

Comment: Also, make sure you have not checked in any default Sitecore JavaScript files into your project, otherwise they will overwrite any newer files when you deploy.

Comment: @xoail I already checked and there doesn't seem to be any errors and the only relevant warning (the one that isn't concerned with memory usage) is : Long running operation: renderContentEditor pipeline[id={2E3AABB3-D15E-4700-9D17-5CB2F143CACB}]

Comment: @jammykam You are completely right, there seems to be two JavaScript errors when trying to select an item in the media item tree on the media selector dialog box: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://{domain_name}/-/speak/v1/rules/CopyNestedPropertiesFromTreeSelectedItem.js" and "Error: Script error http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror"

Comment: @jammykam I found the CopyNestedPropertiesFromTreeSelectedItem.js file in a clean Sitecore project and copied it to my project. Beats me how such a remote and hidden file could have been lost/misplaced. Thank you, you've spared me a lot of headaches. Please formulate your comment into an answer so that I may select it as the answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, check the JavaScript console of your browser to make sure there is no errors. Press F12 to open the dev console and try running the action again.

Make sure you do not have any of the default Sitecore files from a previous version checked into your project, otherwise they will simply overwrite the newer files when you deploy and functionality may break (I had a similar issue recently and it took a while to figure out).

I find [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) really useful, you can [compare entire folders](http://manual.winmerge.org/Compare_dirs.html) and it will tell you if there are file differences and/or missing files. Use the default Sitecore zip version of the root to compare your deployment again.

Comment: Good advice. It's also worth checking the contents of your core database /sitecore/client/Applications/Dialogs as for some reason some values (rules) were missing in one of my environments which caused the same issue. Creating a package and importing fixed it in my scenario